# Better Coding Practice Than If-Else

Tags: c#, if-statement, logic

Lets say I have this code.

```
int count = 0;
int id = GetFirstId();
count = getCountById(id);

if(count == 0){
 id = GetSecondId();
 count = getCountById(id);
  if(count == 0){
    id = GetThirdId();
    count = getCountById(id);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this. Is something like a LOOP and CASE Statement inside better?

Comment: What programming language you are using?

Comment: C# but I think the practice should also be applied to other programming languages?

Comment: If you have many items you should definitely use a switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have different method, you can list the methods and then use LINQ to get first non-zero `count`. It will work if **all** of your `GetXXXId` have same signature.

```
var idGetters = new Func<int>[] 
{
    GetFirstId,
    GetSecondId,
    GetThirdId
    // and so on
};

var count = idGetters
            .Select(x => x())
            .Select(GetCountById)
            .SkipWhile(x => x == 0)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What if the Id is not incrementing. Should I use case inside the loop instead? Then have something like Case(i): id = 15

Comment: I've edited the question. By the way thanks for you answer!

Comment: Alright way to go! I like this solution very well, it is dynamic. Thanks!